# identify multiple beacons in a app

Tags: iphone, ios7, bluetooth, ios8, ibeacon

Im developing an app using beacons. i have multiple beacons within a location and I need to recognise all the beacons.

I have created multiple regions for every beacon.

```
 NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:bID];

 CLBeaconRegion *region  = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"com.test.iBeacon];

 [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

The problem is only the last beacon region is getting recognized. The other beacons are not recognized. Should the beacons have same UUID and different major minor??

Answer (score 0):

Two things to consider:

- First of all, you can only register up to 20 region to monitor
- Last but not least, each of you region must have a different identifier (you can't use 20 times @"com.test.iBeacon")

Comment: thanks for ur reply. is the limit 20 mentioned in Apple docs?

Comment: Yes it is, with the description of the startMonitoringForRegion: method "An app can register up to 20 regions at a time."